# How can I fix this? Python list with input

Tags: python-2.7, list, input

I need to create a code that if you input 1, it will show you the actual list, that is empty, then if you put 2 you'll be able to add "x" to the list, if you press 3 you can remove in the list, and the last thing is if you press 9, you exit python.

Here's the code:

```
list = []
if input == "1":
    print list
if input == "2":
    list.append("hi")
    print list
if input == "3":
    list.remove("hi")
    print list
if input == "9":
    sys.exit()
```

I´ll be glad if someone helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this . 
I thought you meant to take input every-time , so there is an infinite while loop { If I am wrong ,and you meant to take input only once then you can just remove the while loop and it will work fine , then too }.
Also what i thought was from removing an element from list is , you meant to remove the latest element which was inserted in the list , so this code will remove the latest element which was inserted.
Also if there is **any input other than {1,2,3,9}** , the following code will take care of it.

Hopefully , this will solve your problem .

```
import sys
arr = []   #creates an empty list.

while True:

inp = raw_input("Enter the number you want to enter {1,2,3,9} :- ")

if inp == "1":
    print arr;

elif inp == "2":
    temp = raw_input("Enter what you want to add to the list :- ")
    arr.append(temp)
    print arr

elif inp == "3":
    arr = arr[:-1] ## will remove the last element , and will also handle even if there is no element present 
    print arr   

elif inp ==  "9":
    sys.exit()

else: #Any input other than {1,2,3,9}
    print "Please enter the input from {1,2,3,9}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
import sys
list = []
ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
if ch == "1":
    print(list)
if ch == "2":
   list.append("hi")
   print(list)
if ch == "3":
   list.remove("hi")
   print(list)

if ch == "9":
   sys.exit()
```